# User DSN timeout error for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc, user-profile, dsn

A little background: I have 20 or so clients that use a User-DSN to connect to a SQL Server db, to run an Access program.  To date, everything has been working fine.  I use the same SQL Server authentication for each.

The other day, I took an existing computer from "stock" to swap out for an existing user.  When I tried to create their DSN, I get a connection timeout error.  If I use my Domain Admin account, it works fine.  If I log into my computer with the user login, it doesn't work either.  If I log into the users old computer, it works fine.

What confuses me, I am using a SQL Server login for the ODBC credentials, not Windows.  What am I missing?

Comment: Q: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not.  Computer to server communication (ping) works, but the timeout still persists.  While I understand that an ODBC connect using SQL login should not hit the domain, I can't get past the fact that this problem only appears for user logging into computers they have never used before or new logins I create on the domain.  This applies even to doing a "copy as" of my domain admin account.

Comment: " I understand that an ODBC connect using SQL login should not hit the domain"  Q: What makes you think that???  Just because you're using SQL server authentication to log on ... doesn't mean you DON'T need domain-protected resources to establish your connection in the first place.  Please revisit the linksI cited below...

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that a domain user can connect from the PC, but not your intended user ... and since it sounds like your "intended user" is *NOT* a domain user ... then I'm guessing the first thing to check is that your MSSQL instance configured for [Mixed mode authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996524(v=exchg.65).aspx).

Here are some links that might help:

- [Troubleshooting: Timeout Expired](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx),
- [Steps to troubleshoot SQL connectivity issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/),
- [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I confused the issue.  Let me retry:  The user is a domain user and is not a new user account.  In the User DSN I use a SQL Server account, the same one used in all other ODBC connections.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem, but not sure why it works.  I added an inbound Windows Firewall rule on the server, for port 1433 and the users in question can connect.  Not sure why this affected a couple users and not 20 others, but at least it gets the spotlight off me!  Thanks for everyone's input.